# converting base64 to a PDF file and passing in a webservice in JAVA

Tags: java, web-services, pdf, base64

I have a webservice that returns me a base 64 representation of a PDF file. 
I want to write another webservice that will take in the base64 string and convert the base 64 back into a PDF document and pass this PDF document back out to the caller of the webservice. All in JAVA.
Is this possible, considering I will not have actually saved the PDF to a file location? I want to avoid having to share network file locations. All the advice I can find so far talks about files but using filepaths, not actual file objects.

And can I use standard JAVA classes and not extensions?

Thanks

Comment: Do you beforehand know how long the PDF file is? Or can you locally cache (in memory or on disc) it while decoding? In general, streamed base 64 decoding is no problem, but web service result headers in general do contain the content length; therefore my questions...

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, but why would you? Decoding base64 is such a fundamental task that it makes little sense to offload it to a web service -- the infrastructure you need to *invoke* a web service in the first place is overwhelmingly likely to contain/provide a base64 decoder that you could just use locally in the client.

(And it is immaterial that the encoded bytes you decode happen to be a PDF document).

Comment: Hi Henning, Can you explain a little more what you mean. We are using WSO2 to call web services, but may use other tools, we cannot always specify, it depends on the client.

Comment: What I mean is that it is hard to imagine _any_ client platform that is able to make HTTP requests but cannot encode and decode base64 by itself. For example the `Content-MD5` and `WWW-Authenticate` HTTP headers (the latter with Basic authentication) contain base64 encoded data, so a HTTP protocol stack will certainly have encoders and decoders lying around somewhere. It will often be on a lower level that the actual "web service" framework.

Comment: Essentially the only imaginable reasons are that the pdfs are to be directly referenced by Web applications, or that the client programs that shall use the pdf are really dumb.

Comment: Hi again, thanks for your answer. This makes sense - passing only binary or byte data across the wire. The webservice itself does not reference the PDF, correct.

Comment: But - I want a self-contained service. I want to call a service that just takes my XML file, reads the data, creates a PDF based on some of that data and some other stuff, and passes me back the PDF file. I don't want to concern myself with encoding and decoding - why should I?

Comment: @user1769045: That's fine. Perhaps I misunderstood your question? I thought you wanted a service that took a random base64 encoded blob as input and returned that very same blob as binary data after decoding. But you're really looking to _wrap_ the existing service? That makes more sense.

Comment: @user1769045 Is there any chance of actually extending the original service by some parameter (e.g. a HTTP "Accept" header) requesting the reply in some specific format?